# R table remove column

Tags: r

I have a table, let's say:

```
 0 4.5  12  14  24  36  47 
 6   1   1   1   7   1   3
```

I want to remove the column labeled `0` if it exists in the table. The command `t <- t[,!'0', with=FALSE]` did not give me the desired outcome (it resulted in an error).

Comment: Where did the "with=FALSE" idea come from? As far as I know, that's only a `[.data.table` thing... It would be better if you provided a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
> x <- setNames(c(6,1,1,1,7,1,3), c("0", "4.5", "12", "14", "24", "36", "47" ))
> x # your data
  0 4.5  12  14  24  36  47 
  6   1   1   1   7   1   3 
> x <- x[names(x) != "0"]
> x # what you want
4.5  12  14  24  36  47 
  1   1   1   7   1   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract it.

```
x[- which(names(x) == '0')]
```